# How to safely eject a tablespace oracle and move it to another machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I've a tablespace created on a external hardisk with one big datafile. If there are no connections to it, is it safe to eject the disk and plug it into a new machine? And how to map the tablespace to the oracle in the new machine?

Comment: No. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to move the data files from one storage to another storage or do you want to make the tablespace an the data it contains available in a different database or do you want the whole database to a new machine and storage?

Comment: I want to import the table space/ datafile into another database.

Comment: for this you have to do a transportable tablespace export and import.

Comment: You probably want to use a pluggable database, rather than a transportable tablespace.

Answer (score -1):

> If there are no connections to it, is it safe to eject the disk and plug it into a new machine?

No.  Absolutely not.

Database != File

Unless you shutdown the entire database, there is *no guarantee* that changes have been written from the Buffer Cache into the data files that make up that Tablespace.

Making a Tablespace transportable does forces that write activity to happen (and then prevents any more) but without the downtime.  But then, as you say, you have to muck about "mapping" that Tablespace into the new database.  Don't make work for yourself.

Your best option, though (i.e. easiest, most reliable, best supported but, perhaps, not fastest to execute), is to dump (datapump) the data out of one database and into the new one.  Depending on your network connectivity, you might be able to do this over a database link, or might have to resort to moving the dump file between machines.

Comment: No, it is not the best option. Transportable Tablespace is reliable, too, is easy, too, is supported, too, but is much faster.